# Programmatically Add Text In A Content Editable Div In C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a network of blogs that I want to be able to do bulk updates on. Unfortunately these are free blogs and they do not allow ftp, so i'm forced to write a program to interface with their site builder.

The issue I'm having is that they use a content editable div for the text input. I have never worked with these before and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of how I could achieve this. I'm not looking for a solution, but just need to know where to start looking (in C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are custom frameworks for finding your way on the web pages like [Watin](http://watin.org/). You can use it to find the div necessary by id/class/position and set its value. It's also the basis for web page testing.

Another way to go is to see what http requests are sent by the forms for data entering (like POST with form data) and emulate it from code.